# Freeform: Display freeform entries from logged in user

Tags: solspace-freeform

I want to create a page where a user can view and edit his own submitted freeform entries.

The user has to log in before submitting the form.

I have tried this:

```
{exp:freeform:entries
orderby="entry_date" 
sort="desc"
limit="2"
form_id="21"
author_id="{member_id}" 
}
```

And it does not display any entries.
But when I hard code the author_id author_id="1" it works.

So, how do I display form entries submitted by the logged in user only?

Answer (score 1):

Why do use {member_id}? From where this coming from?

Try to use CURRENT_USER if u want show list of entries for current user

```
{exp:freeform:entries
orderby="entry_date" 
sort="desc"
limit="2"
form_id="21"
author_id="CURRENT_USER" 
}
```

Comment: Sorry that does not work. It does not display anything.

Comment: is this site online? if yes - send me message max at eec.ms

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the Member group to disallow the viewing of post made by others.
A long time ago I created a support site which bothered me for a while and I found the above solution would only display entries by the logged in user.